# Computing a large dataset in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am generating a matrix of similarities between items in order to provide it to a recommender system in Django. (it's n^2 at the end of the day.)

The issue I am having is that either if I use `iterator()` or not, my RAM still gets sucked.
I do something like this:

```
rated_apps_list = Rating.objects.values_list('item_id', flat=True).order_by('-item_id').distinct()
rated_apps_iter = MemorySavingQuerysetIterator(rated_apps_list[start:])

for app_above in rated_apps_iter:
    rated_apps_below_iter = MemorySavingQuerysetIterator(rated_apps_list[i+1:])
    for app_below in rated_apps_below_iter:
        ...
```

where MemorySavingQuerySetIterator is:

```
class MemorySavingQuerysetIterator(object):

def __init__(self,queryset,max_obj_num=1000):
    self._base_queryset = queryset
    self._generator = self._setup()
    self.max_obj_num = max_obj_num

def _setup(self):
    for i in xrange(0,self._base_queryset.count(),self.max_obj_num):
        # By making a copy of of the queryset and using that to actually access
        # the objects we ensure that there are only `max_obj_num` objects in
        # memory at any given time
        smaller_queryset = copy.deepcopy(self._base_queryset)[i:i+self.max_obj_num]
        #logger.debug('Grabbing next %s objects from DB' % self.max_obj_num)
        for obj in smaller_queryset.iterator():
            yield obj

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self):
    return self._generator.next()
```

At first I tried just with the .iterator() function but then I believe it was the Database Client who was caching the results.
The leak continues to be there and I have to reload the script after a while.

I know it doesn't look efficient to create as many iterator as elements because then I would end up having all the elements in memory, how would you guys do it?.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: One improvement I see is to just use iterator in each of the external loop iterations, I am going to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your solution is almost ok. There are few advices:

1. Don't `deepcopy` queryset, it's cloned when you slice it anyway.
2. Slicing is inefficient from database perspective (large offset in a sql), it means database needs to prepare many rows and then pass you only few.
3. Slicing is also unsafe if anything can be added or deleted from table in between.

You can adapt [this thing](https://github.com/Suor/handy/blob/0.2.4/handy/db.py#L25) to your case. Just use `item_id` instead of `pk`. It uses condition instead of offset so it's much more efficient.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as valid as it points out the "queryset_iterator" that I found some days ago also in "DjangoSnippets" and it helped improve the performance. As I side note, I am using now a direct MySql prodedure which improves ENORMOUSLY the efficiency, but yes, it has to be ported if the DBMS changes in production. Something I really can afford. Thanks!